# How to make a button press connect a Bluetooth device in visual studio?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, connection

I am making a windows application and part of the setup is to connect to a specific Bluetooth device named "Bluetooth Device 1" when the connect button is pressed. That device will be paired already so no need to worry about that.

When the button is pressed, the windows pc will connect (assuming is paired already) to "Bluetooth Device 1"

Comment: There are 2 APIs: WinSOck and WinRT. Select one and write connection code. Its long code so its hard to write all here.

Comment: Can you help me

Comment: If you are new in Bluetooth you can try to start with thirdparty libs. 32feet or Bluetooth Framework (https://www.btframework.com)